# Why Ruby .map doesn't work with if statement

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm getting an unexpected result with using `if` inside `.map`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.map do |item|
  item + 10 if item < 4
  item + 9  if item > 4
end
```

I expected: `[11,12,13,13,14]`
...but I'm instead getting: `[nil, nil, nil, nil, 14]`

Why's that?

Secondly, I know that the last expression is the return value of method
So does this true with if statement? The last expression is the return value of if statement.

Thanks!

Comment: hint: the return value of an if where the condition wasn't true is nil

Answer (score 2):

For elements that are < 4, `item + 10 if item < 4` does indeed return the expected value. But then the second statement executes, and map returns *that* value. For item < 4, `item + 9 if item > 4` returns `nil`.

Your map should look like this instead:

```
a.map do |item|
  if item < 4 then
      item + 10
  else
      item + 9
  end
end
```

What do you do if item == 4?

Comment: Oh, I got an exercise that use this map. And inside that map, I put several if statements but it doesn't work as I expected. So the example above just to demonstrate my question. I don't mind it so maybe I forgot the case of item == 4

Answer (score 2):

We can demonstrate the problem you have by writing the block as a method:

```
def test_map(item)
  item + 10 if item < 4
  item + 9  if item > 4
end

test_map 3
# => nil
test_map 5
# => 14
```

What happens here? For `item=3` the first line returns `13`, but that's not what's returned from the method - the method continues to the next line, which is evaluated to `nil`...

In order to return a single value according to several conditions, you can use `if..elsif..else` construct, or a [`case..when`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) construct:

```
def test_map2(item)
  case item
    when 0..4
      item + 10
    when 4..10
      item + 9
    else
      item
  end
end

test_map2 3
# => 13
test_map2 5
# => 14
```

`case..when` returns the block after the *first* `when` clause which is evaluated to true.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby 2.7+**

*There be a solution now!*

Ruby 2.7 is introducing `filter_map` for this exact purpose. It's idiomatic and performant, and I'd expect it to become the norm very soon.

For example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13]
enum.filter_map { |i| i * 2 if i.even? }
# => [4, 16, 20]
```

Here's a [good read on the subject](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/05/25/ruby-2-7-enumerable-filter-map.html).

Hope that's useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you use `map`, you create array containing values evaluated from block passed into `map` method. So in this case, the last value evaluated in first 4 elements is `item + 9  if item > 4`, which returns `nil`.

Comment: so does that mean the last expression in the block will be returned to map as each element iterator through?